# POCO Classes with WCF Service - how proxy generator works / interoperability

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm reading through *Programming Entity Framework 4.0* and I'm on POCO & WCF chapter.

After generating proxy classes, I took a glimpse at generated code:

```
public partial class StateObject : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    /* ........... */
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public ConsoleApplicationPOCO.POCOCustomerService.State State {
        get {
            return this.StateField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.StateField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.StateField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And a few question arouse in my head:

- how does code generator know how to implement setter methods, in particular calling **RaisePropertyChanged** method and the **if** statement
- how generator knows how to implement **protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)**
- author says that this solution can be used with clients that do not use .NET. How come, if we are still depend on **INotifyPropertyChanged** and **IExtensibleDataObject**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The generator looks at the DataMembers exposed by the target class and creates one property with a getter and setter for each one.

2) Microsoft decided that the generated classes would implement the `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so each generated setter includes a call to `RaisePropertyChanged` to support this interface. This is part of the reason for needing a full property setter.

3) This is just Microsoft's client implementation for the service. If you add a reference to the service from another programming IDE, you will not get the .Net framework-specific generated code. That IDE will generate the service reference code according to its own needs.